# php-fpm : disabling a php extension for a specific pool

Tags: php, mysql, fpm

I have configured a new FPM pool (config file `www.conf` in `pool.d`), now let's say I want to disable mysql support for that specific pool ? Or maybe there is a way **not** to load that extension for that pool ?

I'm using debian 9 and here is how the file structure looks like this:

```
/etc/php/7.0/fpm$ tree
.
├── conf.d
│   ├── 10-mysqlnd.ini -> /etc/php/7.0/mods-available/mysqlnd.ini
│   ├── 10-opcache.ini -> /etc/php/7.0/mods-available/opcache.ini
│   ├── 10-pdo.ini -> /etc/php/7.0/mods-available/pdo.ini
│   ├── 20-calendar.ini -> /etc/php/7.0/mods-available/calendar.ini
│   ├── 20-ctype.ini -> /etc/php/7.0/mods-available/ctype.ini.ini
(...)
├── php-fpm.conf
├── php.ini
└── pool.d
    ├── forgewww.conf
    └── www.conf
```

`extension=thing.so` can be found in files `conf.d/<extension>.ini`. Problem is all those extensions once configured seem common to all pools...

I've also tried to disable mysql extensions globally with `phpdismod` then append a line in `www.conf` with:

```
php_admin_value[extension] = mysqli.so
```

Which doesn't seems to work (the above doesn't enable mysqli for that pool)

Comment: disabling is hard if not impossible. in the default ini, there might be a line `extension=mysql[something]` that enables it. if the pool loads its own ini, you can remove/comment that line.

Comment: Thanks but extensions doesn't seem loaded that way at least on debian. I tried others tricks (see my edits) but with no more success.

Comment: You can't disable extension on a pool basis. You have to boot up an entirely separate `php-fpm`, using a different socket, which in turn enables/disables extensions you want.

Comment: @Mjh thanks. that's too bad. If you are 100% sure your answer might be a correct answer for stackoverflow ?

Comment: I'm 100% sure, fpm can't load different extensions per pool because it forks the child processes. It can't unload something per pool. Although it might be possible to create such a solution at some point, there's no real merit because you get around this by simply spinning another fpm on a different port or socket, loading extensions you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't load different extension per-pool, the extensions are defined in an `.ini` file, loaded by master process. `php-fpm` master process forks into children, meaning that they share what's been loaded by the master process. You can't have a child load a different set of extensions after forking, or unload them. It probably is possible to develop a solution, but there's really no need for that seeing that you can solve your problem via different approach.

In order to achieve what you're after, simply set up entirely different php-fpm process on a different port / unix socket and load extensions you require, set up your pools and you're done. It's actually a lot less work than it sounds, it probably won't take you more than a few minutes.

Comment: Looks to me it implies adding a copy of the init script /etc/init.d/php7.0-fpm  too

Comment: Good answer. Could you expand it to include steps involved?